# What to use: threading or multiprocessing or rq or gevents for a database related use case

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I want to run concurrent processes for this flow:

`table A` has rows and each row has : `source` and `destination` connections with `start-time` and `time-interval` for querying the `source` to insert into `destination`. Now, the `time_interval` can be different like `1 day` or `1 month` for different rows. So, each process fetches these details, queries the source, and inserts into `destination`. The start-time now becomes `start-time + interval`.

I want to run every row of A concurrently. What should be the best way to go about it, using `threading` / `multiprocessing` / `rq` / `gevents`/ `any other implementation`, for example, multithreading with queues

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Multi-Thread is faster but it can give problems when you have shared objects/variables. Multiprocess avoid this case with an appropriated synchronization, with semaphores for example.

Comment: Thanks for your post. For this task, I wouldn't have many shared objects as mostly there will be different source and destination tables (there might be though when writing to the same table). I am thinking of using multiprocessing.